# (Rails) Heroku deployments looks for controller that no longer exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4

Hey I am trying to deploy my rails app on Heroku, but I receive and error code 10 (app crashed) every  time. When I run the "heroku run bundle exec rails console" command, I can see that it's looking for a controller that I deleted long ago and don't rely anymore, why is this and how can I fix it? Much appreciated!

This is the error, it looks for "items_controller" even though I deleted that file weeks ago and my app works in local

```
unning `bundle exec rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.7812
/app/app/controllers/items_controller.rb:26: warning: else without rescue is useless
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-    4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require':     /app/app/controllers/items_controller.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting     keyword_then or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
```

Comment: Post error logs, might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may not have removed it from the git repository, even though you deleted it locally.

Comment: Ah yes that is true, how do I go about deleting all the files from my repo that are not currently on my local machine?

Comment: You can use `git rm filename` if you are using git.  Or just use `git add . --all` if you want to blanket it.

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm --cached app/controllers/items_controllers.rb
```

Commit it, push to heroku. If that does not work:

```
heroku run bash
```

Navigate to controllers and see if items controller is there.